# How to append the value in option element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one form field called country and one more field state. Suppose i select India. That means I want show only which cities in INDIA. Suppose i select USA means i want show only which cities in USA,from this i wrote select query this and all correct, but i can't append the value in state field.. `console.log(res);`

Here I have the correct value, but I can't append this value in state field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getState(country_id){
//console.log(country_id);
$.ajax({
    url:'getstate.php',
    type:'POST',
    data : { 'country_id' : country_id},
    success:function(data){
        var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
        console.log(res);
        if(res['status']==1){

           var htmlString='';
           $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
               htmlString+='<select>';
               htmlString+='<option>'+value.state_name+'</option>';

               htmlString+='</select>';
              //console.log( key + ": " + value.name );
            });
            $('#state').empty().append(htmlString);

        }

    },
});
};
</script>
```

getstate.php

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
$country_id = $_POST['country_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state WHERE country_id='$country_id'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$return=array();
if($count > 0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $data[]=$row;
    }
    $return=array('status'=>1,'count'=>$count,'data'=>$data);
}else{
    $return=array('status'=>0,'count'=>$count,'data'=>'');
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

```html
<tr>
<th>COUNTRY</th>
<td>
    <select name="country" id="country" onchange="getState(this.value);">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <?php
        include("dbconfig.php");
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['country_name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="country_err"></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>STATE</th>
    <td>
        <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="">Select State</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="state_err"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you empty `$('#state').empty()` it empty all options inside `$('#state')` dropdown not state element completely. So, you no need to add the `htmlString+='<select>';` and `htmlString+='</select>';` again.

Try below script,

```
function getState(country_id){
//console.log(country_id);
    $.ajax({
    url:'getstate.php',
    type:'POST',
    data : { 'country_id' : country_id},
    success:function(data){
        var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
        console.log(res);
        if(res['status']==1){

           var htmlString='<option value="">Select State</option>';
           $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
               //htmlString+='<select>'; //  COMMENT THIS AND THIS IS WRONG
               htmlString+='<option>'+value.state_name+'</option>'; // You missed to add "value" attribute. Please add if required 

               //htmlString+='</select>'; //  COMMENT THIS AND THIS IS WRONG
              //console.log( key + ": " + value.name );
            });
            $('#state').empty().append(htmlString);

        }
      },
    });
};
```

Note:- You missed to add "value" attribute for the state option. Please add if required

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks @user6838959

Comment: @Machavity thanks for the instruction. Yes, you are correct and I will definitely improve the quality of post.

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors in how you are appending the dynamic contents of your ajax-response.

in your following Code, you are addind  the list (select) to itself and this is wrong AND your generated options have no values, only labels as you do here:

```
$.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
               htmlString+='<select>'; // WRONG since your target Element is the Select element
               htmlString+='<option>'+value.state_name+'</option>';

               htmlString+='</select>';
              //console.log( key + ": " + value.name );
            });
            $('#state').empty().append(htmlString);
```

now you could rewrite it like this:

```
    $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {                   
        htmlString += '<option value="'+value.state_id+'">';
        htmlString += value.state_name;
        htmlString += '</option>';
   });
   $('#state').empty().append(htmlString);
```